# Excel table auto update

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

So I have a table in Excel with formulas.  When I add a new row, the new row automatically fills in the formulas as well, which is great.  My problem is that it also changes the formula in the row above the added row as well.  Here's what happens specifically:

My table's last row is row 24.  A formula I have in that row is the following:

=COUNTIF(C$11:C24,"y")/(COUNTIF(C$11:C24,"Y")+COUNTIF(C$11:C24,"N"))

When I add in data in row 25 the formula is updated in row 25 as well, which is what I want, to the following:

=COUNTIF(C$11:C25,"y")/(COUNTIF(C$11:C25,"Y")+COUNTIF(C$11:C25,"N"))

My problem is that the row above also updates - my row 24 changes to the same as row 25 (the C24 goes to C25).  Why is my row 24 formula changing when I add a row 25?  Note, my formulas above row 24 stay the same when I add in row 25 - only row 24 changes when I add in 25.  Is there a way to not update the row above the row being added?

This problem continues when additional rows are added - If I add in a row 26, then the formula in rows 24-26 then all reference C26.  Why are they all updating?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more official way to do this, but you could make use of the `INDIRECT` formula here. `INDIRECT` allows you to state the range in your formulas using a string. This allows you to concatenate strings together and have it come out as a range. For instance if `A1` has the value `16` in it, the formula `=INDIRECT("A1")` would be `16`. Furthermore the formula `=INDIRECT("A" & "1")` would be `16`.

The way to write your formula using INDIRECT would be:
`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C11:C" & ROW()),"y")/(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C11:C" & ROW()),"Y")+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C11:C" & ROW()),"N"))`

Now when new rows are added to your table, Excel won't try to expand your range for you and the `ROW` formula will provide you with the dynamic logic needed so the correct range is selected for your formula.